Extracting text from a string in Pandas
I'm trying to create two new columns by extracting text from strings in an existing column in a Pandas dataframe.
Dataframe
I would like to create two new columns from portions of stings in column Sample ID. I’m not great at regex and have been struggling to get the right expressions.

I would like to extract the Sample ID name B/TP-1. This name will vary in the dataframe (B/TP-1, B/TP-2 and so on).

I would like to extract the depth 0.5 from the Sample ID. These depths may vary in the dataframe (0.5, 2.5, 5, 10, 15 and so on).


IN an attempt to extract the depth I’ve tried the following expression and several slightly different expressions, but it did not give me only the depth for each sample (see example output).
pattern = r'B/TP-6-(\d+\d+)

SAMPDATA_w['Sample ID2'] = SAMPDATA_w['Sample ID'].apply(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x) .group(1) if re.search(pattern, x) else None)

Dataframe with attempted output
I've also not been able extract just the sample ID.

Well, yes; your regex is looking specifically for "B/TP-6", not "B/TP-1".  Did you try "(B/TP-\d)"?

You can do the following :
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sample_ID_original': ['B/TP-1-0.5', 'B/TP-1-0.25']
})

# Separate the str by the '-'

df[['Sample_ID', 'Number', 'Depth']] = df['Sample_ID_original'].str.split('-', expand=True)

# Concatenate the Number to the Sampe_ID

df['Sample_ID'] = df['Sample_ID'].str.cat(df[['Number']].values,sep=' - ')

# Drop the Number Column

df = df.drop(columns=['Number'], axis=1)



Change the pattern and use str.extract:
df = pd.DataFrame({"Sample ID": ["B/TP-1-0.5", "B/TP-1-0.25"]})

pattern = r"(B/TP-\d+)-(\d+\.*\d*)"
df[["name", "depth"]] = df["Sample ID"].str.extract(pattern)

     Sample ID    name depth
0   B/TP-1-0.5  B/TP-1   0.5
1  B/TP-1-0.25  B/TP-1  0.25

